# Image Size Comparison (Realtime?)

Tags: image, real-time

For a iPhone app, how would I go about this process. I want to take a picture of say, a quarter and a penny, then I want it to recognize the two coins and tell me which is bigger. Is this possible, if so, what sort of code or process would I need to preform?

Comment: What do you mean by "bigger"? Do you mean you want actually recognize the dimensions of arbitrary objects? Do you mean you want your program to know the value of the coins?

Answer (score 2):

If you have two pictures of something that is roughly circular, it should not be difficult to tell the size of the circle *in the image*, but it can actually be very difficult to tell the size of *the actual circular item*, as the size in the image is dependent not only on the size of the actual object, but also on the distance from the camera to the object, and so you'd probably need other content in the image to infer the distance.

Now, if you are only taking pictures of coins, you should be able to infer the size based on the type of coin. Of course, this might not always work (e.g. when taking a picture of a giant-sized poster of a penny, for example). You'll need to clarify your requirements a bit in order to get a better answer.

Comment: I don't need to know the exact size, I just need to know the size of it in the image. Because I just want it for size comparison. How would I find the size of a circular object in an image via code?